# ORDS - Oracle Rest Data Services 503 error

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-apex, oracle18c, oracle-ords

[image]

installation : oracle database 19c
apex 20.1
apache tomcat
ords 18.4
and apache httpd for proxy and caching

i am getting this error on sign on ... please help. tried resetting the apex pub userpassword, unlocking the already unlocked account... idk what else to try... article out there are very vague when it comes to this error

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Oracle REST Data Service apex\_pu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30196252/oracle-rest-data-service-apex-pu)

Comment: I will try this and get back to you on this thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Go into your ORDS config directory. There will be an XML file in there for each connection pool. Edit it and update the password field as below.

```
conf/apex.xml -- Put a ! in front of the password

<entry key="db.password">!NewPASSWORD</entry>
```

You need to restart ORDS for it to pick up any changes in its config files.

Read more on: [How to Update the ORDS_PUBLIC_USER Password](https://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2017/06/how-to-update-the-ords_public_user-password/)